# Fixing a failed integrity check in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I just did `hg pull` on a repository and brought in some changesets. It said to run `hg update`, so I did. Unfortunately, when I did that, it failed with the following error message:

```
abort: integrity check failed on 00manifest.i:173!
```

When I run `hg verify`, it tells me there are a number of issues with things not in the manifest (with some slight path obscuring):

```
>hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
 somewhere1/file1.aspx@172: in changeset but not in manifest
 somewhere2/file1.pdf@170: in changeset but not in manifest checking files
 file3.csproj@172: ee005cae8058 not in manifests
 somewhere2/file1.pdf@171: 00371c8b9d95 not in manifests
 somewhere3/file1.ascx@170: 5c921d9bf620 not in manifests
 somewhere4/file1.ascx@172: 23acbd0efd3a not in manifests
 somewhere5/file1.aspx@170: ce48ed795067 not in manifests
 somewhere5/file2.aspx@171: 15d13df4206f not in manifests
1328 files, 174 changesets, 3182 total revisions
8 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 170)
```

The source repository passes `hg verify` just fine.

Is there any way to recover from an integrity check failure or do I need to re-clone the repository completely from the source (not a huge issue in this case)? What could I have done to cause this, so I don't do it again?

Comment: A typical way to get into this problem is by doing things like `del *.pdf* /s`, this will wipe out relevant files inside the .hg directory as well, which is *bad*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, since the first damaged changeset is 170, you could clone your local repository to 169 and then pull from the source. That means only pulling 5 changesets.

```
hg clone -r 169 damagedrepo fixedrepo
cd fixedreop
hg verify
```

And then:

```
hg pull originalsource
```

As for manual recovery of repository corruption, [this page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) expounds on that better than I can. See section 4:

> I have found corruption once in a while before, and although the above
> documentation says it is usually from user error, my instances were on
> removable USB drives with empty working directories. Sometimes things
> just don't get written correctly or are interfered with somehow: it's
> not always user error. But I always have multiple copies I can reclone
> from so I've been able to get away with basic fixing.

If the simple fix of a partial local clone and pulling from the server doesn't fix it, you're down to 2 options after backing up your changes (if any) to a bundle or patches:

- Manually hacking at Mercurial's files.
- Doing a new full clone from the server. Usually the easier and faster of the two.

Comment: I did the `hg clone -r 169 {crap} {new}` and did `hg pull` for the rest. When I ran `hg update`, it got `abort: integrity check failed on 00manifest.i:173!` again. For fun, I also tried going back further (165) with no luck.

Comment: Did the clone `verify` alright before pulling? Does `verify` produce the same output as before after pulling? What happens if you only pull 1 changeset at a time? (Use `incoming` first, of course.) What happens if you do an entirely new clone from source? **:)**

Comment: Version 169 did verify successfully, but I got the integrity check failure on `hg incoming`. Pulled revision 170 and the verify message changes (subset of "not in manifest" entries, but also a "missing revlog" on one of those files). Cloning from source worked fine.

Comment: Interesting. And odd. Next thing I would try is cloning the new full clone to 169 and pull from source, just to see what happens. I'm going to make an addendum to my answer, though.

Comment: @patridge: Update Mercurial to the newest version before cloning.

Comment: I just installed the latest download on this fairly new Win7 install two days ago and it [appears to be the same](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) one available now. I did a repair anyway, cloned (-r 169), and I still get the integrity check failures (on incoming and pull=>update). Since cloning fresh from the source worked just fine, I should probably just call it quits on this exercise and hope it never happens again.

Comment: @Joel you're sure your USB drives don't have reliability issues?

Comment: @tonfa: They did. Most instances were because the 2.5" HD in my Seagate GoFlex was defective, so I replaced it. Started off occasional and got worse. Couple instances happened with an encrypted flash stick, too. The point of the anecdote is that it was hardware malfunction and not user error. Re-reading it a day later, my tense may be misleading.

Comment: @Joel yeah Mercurial is very good at finding defective drives ;)

Comment: Anecdotal - in about ~1 year I've had this occur 3x working with a remote clone over a Windows networking file share (mapped drive). It *may* be due to concurrent access - ie a push & a pull at the same moment. Not certain. The remote clone is always accessed via the network, and its the only one to ever develop this problem. (No local ones)

Answer (score 8):

**Beware: This method will change all hashes.**

---

Actually there is another way to recover the repository when it is corrupted like this -

You can do a complete rebuild of the repository by using the convert extension. See Section 4.5 on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Recovery_using_convert_extension

First enable the convert extension by adding the following to your ~/.hgrc file

```
[extensions]
convert=
```

Then convert the bad repo to create a fixed repo:

```
$ hg convert --config convert.hg.ignoreerrors=True REPO REPOFIX
```

This worked for me when I had the experience of suddenly finding that there were missing files in the manifests - "error 255".

Answer (score 0):

Try remove your file `00manifest.i` from repo and next use `hg remove 00manifest.i` and `hg commit` commands. Worked for me.

Comment: Removing 00manifest.i is easy enough, but what did you do next?

Answer (score -1):

What we ended up doing was making a new copy of our 'central' repository, deleting the .hg folder in this copy, creating a new repository there (hg init), and then working with this as the central repository.

Be aware however this is only an appropriate solution if you don't need your changeset history other than as a reference (which we don't). You can still use your old central repository for this purpose.