# Mercurial complains repository is corrupt when its not

Tags: mercurial

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and using hg 2.5.2

I did a hg init and am trying to clone a repository using hg clone, hg dies with the following error

transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: integrity check failed on 00changelog.i:16630!

I am pretty sure the repository isn't corrupted because I cloned the same repository on three or four other machines, this is specific to my machine.

Sometimes it fails with different errors (corrupted MAC on input) or at different points integrity check failed on 00changelog.i:11090!

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You hg init'ed a directory, tried to clone that repository, and got that error message?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. This is what I did. 

hg init,
hg clone ssh://user@repository -----> This is where I got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is some optimization that is turned on by default in Ubuntu 12.04 onwards. 
This fixed the problem

ethtool -K eth0 rx off tx off

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to run `hg verify` on remote repository and on your local copy.  What does it say?
2. Update your Mercurial to the newest version.
3. Do you clone on hard drive?  Then try to clone on another hard drive or on USB drive.  And vice versa: if you clone on USB drive then try to clone on hard drive.  Bad storage devices are a common reason of repository corruption as people say in comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543049/458723).