# Phabricator, Diffusion, Mercurial: "abort: integrity check failed"

Tags: mercurial

My Phabricator stopped pulling new commits a few days ago, I tried to look at my repository in Diffusion, but an error occured:

```
Command failed with error #255!
COMMAND
hg --config ui.ssh='/var/www/phabricator/bin/ssh-connect' files --print0 --rev ''\''d753179d2d3defe5b6504c0f4d30f1dd9fb72766'\''' -I '.'
STDOUT
(empty)
STDERR
abort: integrity check failed on 00changelog.i:42440!
```

42440 was the last commit pulled from my repository. Is that a problem with my repo or with Phabricator? I cannot find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a [problem with your clone of repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543020/fixing-a-failed-integrity-check-in-mercurial). you can use any of described in related topic methods (starting from `hg verify` locally and remote) and *if* 42440 is damaged only in your clone get new good clone

JFYI: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption

Comment: I was trying to fix my clone several times, but with no success. Finally I just created new repository in Diffusion, cloned my repo and copied it to the old broken one. Then I updated my repo and now everything seems to work absolutely fine. Thanks for help